# Loop over results from a single row to JOIN table for multiple definition matching

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join / loop over some data but not sure how to do it using only Mysql nested / WHERE IN type queries. I have one table that looks like this

```
id, code1, code2, code3, code4........... code20
1   12     41     1                       55
```

So a lot of columns, they don't all have values, but of the ones that do, I need to take each of those codes and return a row for the code from a table that looks like this:

```
codeid, description
1       item1
12      item12
13      item13 
41      item41
...
```

I was hoping I could use a wildcard in my select for the columns like

```
SELECT description FROM table2 WHERE IN(SELECT code* FROM table1)
```

It doesn't look like the wildcard is possible from my googling, but someone here may know a trick. How can I take all the values from the first table as a list, run the query on it to return the definitions of each code as separate rows?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use a wildcard.  This is a problem with your data structure.  Whenever you have columns that are only distinguished by numbers, you probably have an issue with the data model.

Instead, you should have a table with one row per `id` and per `code`.

You can do something like:

```
select t2.description
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t2.code in (t1.code1, t1.code2, . . . )
             );
```

Performance will not be very good.  For that, see the first suggestion for fixing the data model.

Comment: I completely agree that the data model is crap, unfortunately it isn't mine to fix, just integrating with it. Thank you so much - trying it now :)

Comment: Did you mean to use `select 1`? I am getting an error while implementing it in this way. To be fair I am using an ODBC connection to a C-Tree database. In `most` ways it is compatible with Mysql commands, but sometimes it trips me up.

Comment: @Alan . . . Yes.  I always use `select 1` with `exists` and `not exists` because it is the easiest expression to type.